# currying and rest and spread operators

Tags: javascript, currying

I found this snippet of code in a currying article from a few years ago, but the author didn't explain how it works. I understand where the fn and args1 variables are coming from, but I'm having a hard time understanding what args2 would contain throughout the process and was wondering if anybody could offer insight?

```
function curry(fn, ...args1) { 
    return (...args2) => { fn(...args1, ...args2); } 
}
```

Comment: This is [not currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application). It's partial application!

Comment: What was the point of the article if it didn't explain anything? Also, can you please link it?

Comment: @Bergi I think the point is that it creates a currying function? Maybe my definition of curry isn't quite correct though.

Comment: @zfrisch Except that it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`curry` returns a function. When that returned function is invoked, it may be passed its own arguments. Those are referenced by `args2`.

```js
function curry(fn, ...args1) { 
    console.log("args1 = ", ...args1);
    return (...args2) => { 
      console.log("args2 = ", ...args2);
      fn(...args1, ...args2);
    } 
}

function myFunc(...allArgs) {
  console.log(...allArgs);
}

const curried = curry(myFunc, 1,2,3);

curried(4,5,6);
```

So as you can see, when `fn` is invoked (which is a reference to `myFunc`), it receives all the `args1` and the `args2`, so it displays `1 2 3 4 5 6`.

Comment: Awesome. Glad it was helpful.